# How to sort a List of string by Numeric Order in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, sorting

I have the follow code:

```
x='10 0 17 5'
a = x.split(' ')
first = a.pop(0)
print(first)
print(a)
c  = a.sort(key=int)
print(c)
```

I am removing the 1st element and I want to sort the remaining
This is what I am getting:

```
10
['0', '17', '5']
None
```

Where we see None, I was expecting to see ['0', '5', '17'], as per this post- [Sort a List of string by Numeric Order](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-list-sort-tutorial-examples/).

Why it is not working?

Comment: Because `sort` operates on place and returns None

Comment: Print `a` or use `sorted` instead

Comment: Mad Physicist marked as duplicated?. Why? Cant you see that the other question is trying sort numbers instead of strings (of numbers). It doesn't work the others solution !!

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the question you're asking. Look at the problem the other user experiences and your problem. They are identical. The solution presented in the other question covers your case completely. My other comments should help too. Please read carefully.

Comment: I am going to update with the proposed solution.

Comment: I've tried all previous solution before open the post here. And even the solution in the post - Sort a List of string by Numeric Order that is exactly as mine.  As you can see. It didn't work

Comment: Could you explain me please how `a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]` is equal to `x='10 0 17 5'` ?

Comment: Your question has nothing actually to do with `x = '10 0 17 5'`. Your updates look like you read the linked questions (which *don't* work) but did not pay attention to the answers. Please read carefully. I really can't help you if you're expecting a copy and paste job.

Comment: "I am going to update with the proposed solution." **Please do not do this**. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. The question is **not** there to solve the problem in your code; it is there to help build a searchable library of questions and answers.